# Summing values per month to plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I need to plot the monthly sum of the volumes of a stock for every month from 2000 to 2019. Right now, I have this code:

```
yearList = [j for j in range(2001,2020)]  
yearsplits= np.searchsorted(years, yearList)
volumeYears=np.searchsorted(sp_volume, yearsplits)
for j in range(19):
    print(" {}:  {:12.0f}".format(j+2000, volumeYears[j].sum()))


months = dates.astype('datetime64[M]').astype(int)  # this is a sequence increasing by 1 every month
months -= months[0]   #to skip the months before 1/1/2000
monthsplits = np.searchsorted(months, range(1, 19*12+2))
# from 1/1/2000 to 12/31/2018 are 19years * 12months, and Jan,Feb 2019 at the end 
volumeMonths=np.searchsorted(sp_volume, monthsplits)
for j in range(19):
    print(" {}:  {:12.0f}".format(j+2000, volumeMonths[j].sum()))
```

but `volumeMonths` and `volumeYears` are returning all zeros, which leads to `volumeMonths.sum()` and `volumeYears.sum()` also returning zeros. How do I get the actual sum of the volumes for each month?

Comment: what is the content of `years` and `sp_volume`?

Comment: Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Forget about months and sums for now. The first issue is that `volumeYears` is all zeros. Solve that and the rest will likely become clear. To solve that you need to look at `sp_volume` and `yearsplits`. Unless you share what they are with us, we can't help you.